# Tab navigation not horizontally scrolling on iOS, even with -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch

Tags: html, ios, css, overflow, navigationbar

I've created a mobile sub-navigation bar, which is essentially a row of tabs to switch between pages. When there are too many tabs to fit on the screen, they are supposed to scroll horizontally, using the `overflow: scroll` property. This works on Android, but not on any browser on iOS. I've tried adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` to the scrolling element but this doesn't fix the problem. I've tried everything I've found online, and nothing has worked. Do you have any ideas? Here is the CSS for the scrolling nav bar.

[image: Here's a picture of the nav.]

```
.toggle-bar {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: HTML and CSS are tied at the hip, please update this question with the HTML as well, and in the future if you are asking for help using CSS please include any relevant HTML.

Comment: Try to use inline code markup to highlight code inside your text, and try to use proper indentation in code examples, and proper closing element to wrap your code: {...} (...). And when posting CSS code examples, try to also post related HTML to give people a better idea of what are you trying to build.